# Localhost: "This site can’t provide a secure connection"

Tags: tomcat, ssl, network-programming, port

I have a server running on Tomcat on port 8080. When I go to `localhost:8080` I see the proper Tomcat startup page. But, when I try to go to my desired app, which is running at `localhost:8080/my-site` I get a SSL-Error saying "This site can’t provide a secure connection". I cannot figure out what's wrong.

My logs in Tomcat refer to memcached, but I don't even think I'm running it. They read

```
2017-09-18 17:18:19.176 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@44d6a8bb
2017-09-18 17:18:19.176 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Reconnecting due to failure to connect to {QA sa=w1qamc03.web1.mlbam.net/10.50.54.34:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0}
java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:629)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:409)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.run(MemcachedConnection.java:1334)
```

I'm totally stuck here. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using chrome when you receive this message, do you have the option to click 'Advanced' in the bottom left corner and then click something like 'proceed anyway'? You are probably using HTTPS with a self signed certificate and you need to add it to your allowed CA list

Comment: Boy...do I feel like an idiot. Thanks!

Comment: @LiamKelly this no longer works with chrome. It doesn't give you the option to click through it. It literally started happening to me overnight, with no changes to my app (in this case, Wordpress). I even completely re-installed Xampp to no avail.

Comment: @Alison this is more a work around, there is a better way to solve the problem. Open Chrome, then go to Settings -> Manage Certificates then find the certificate (public key with self signed signature) used by your web server.  This should permanently import the certificate in your browser.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Click 'Advanced' in the bottom left corner and then click something like 'proceed anyway. Your app is implementing HTTPS with a self signed certificate and you need to add it to your allowed CA list

Comment: bottom left corner of what?

Comment: This is no longer possible in the latest versions of Chrome.

Comment: Any other ways to do @atomCode